# How to enumerate and delete stored credentials in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

(Swift beginner question)
In ObjC, you could enumerate and delete specific credentials doing something like this:

```
NSDictionary *credentials;

credentials = [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] credentialsForProtectionSpace:networkHelper.protectionSpace];

[credentials enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    NSURLCredential *credential = obj;
    [[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] removeCredential:credential forProtectionSpace:networkHelper.protectionSpace];
}];
```

I am trying to port that to Swift, but I am having difficulties with the compiler, in that method `credentialsForProtectionSpace` returns a type `[NSObject: AnyObject]?`. Therefore, I wanted to ask the community, what is the correct way to enumerate and delete stored credentials in Swift? I came up with this code, but I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it. In particular, I am concerned about the castings going on.

```
if let credentials = NSURLCredentialStorage.sharedCredentialStorage().credentialsForProtectionSpace(networkHelper.protectionSpace) {
    for (index, element) in enumerate(credentials) {
        NSURLCredentialStorage.sharedCredentialStorage().removeCredential(element.1 as! NSURLCredential, forProtectionSpace: networkHelper.protectionSpace)
    }
}
```